infored that method in the coVerify{} was not called, but the method was called actually
@Test
    fun `test save function`(): Unit = runBlocking {
        mongoCollection = mockk(relaxed = true)
        coEvery { MongoConnection.getCollection<FunctionDO>("functions") } returns mongoCollection

        // replaceOne() was called here
        mongoFunctionRepo.save(f)

        coVerify(exactly = 1){
            mongoCollection.replaceOne(
                capture(filtersCaptor),
                capture(functionDOCaptor),
                capture(replaceOptionsCaptor)
            )
        }


    }
}


replaceOne() was called in save()method
override suspend fun save(f: Function) {
        MongoConnection.getCollection<FunctionDO>(FUNCTION_TABLE).replaceOne(
            Filters.eq(FunctionDO::id.name, f.id.s), f.toMongo(), ReplaceOptions().upsert(true)
        )
    }
}

I try adding log in replaceOne() method and can comfirmed it was called.
Error information:
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: MongoCollection(#1).replaceOne(slotCapture(), slotCapture(), slotCapture(), any())) was not called
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: MongoCollection(#1).replaceOne(slotCapture(), slotCapture(), slotCapture(), any())) was not called
I noticed that there were four arguments in the error information. Would it be the reason of the problem?

How did you add the log in the replaceOne() method when that method is inside the MongoDB library?
